# monitoring and logging /dev/pts/1, under linux

Tags: linux, terminal, pty, pts

I want to monitor and log a pseudo-terminal device /dev/pts/12  (for debugging purposes), i.e. I want to see what gets written to the terminal and I do not want any process using the terminal to notice.

The obvious solution

```
     cat /dev/pts/1 
     cat </dev/pts/1
```

does not work: at best, it seems to capture only keystrokes.

In other words, I'd like to have something analogous to the output of 
  script -t file.timings typescript ;
but I also need the keystrokes. Reptyr -l $PID is another program that might help: it redirects 
the output of a process $PID to another /dev/pts or pipes.

Comment: If you do not mind a kernel patch, see e.g. [ttyrpld](http://ttyrpld.sf.net/)

Answer (score -1):

For normal tty's you got screendump or even cat the vcs file but afaik there is no way to do that on a pseudo-terminal, at least the easy way, maybe you should look this:

[Conspy](http://ace-host.stuart.id.au/russell/files/conspy/)

Hope this helps